# Codeigniter like Database class

Tags: php, sql, database, pdo

I am moving onto making some open source software for kicks, from scratch (not using a framework) and I was building my own database class to use, so queries would be simpler and all run through the same methods.

Ideally it would work like codeigniters database class:

```
$db->where("field", "value");
$db->get();
```

So on and so forth, and decided I may as well not reinvent the wheel if there is already something out there like it, though google searching didn't bring me much.

Any ideas? Thanks guys.

Comment: umm... CI is open source right? ... :|

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out Idiorm, a fluent query builder for PHP5+.

https://github.com/j4mie/idiorm